# JS replace doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I try to replace some text from div, example from console:

```
>"<br>* Please add email(s)!<br>* Please add email(s)!".replace(/<br>* Please add email(s)!/g,'')
```

result:

```
<-"<br>* Please add email(s)!<br>* Please add email(s)!"
```

Comment: How do you try to replace them at the moment?

Comment: Try back slashing? `replace(/\<br\>\* Please add email\(s\)\!/g,'');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the regex to `/<br>\* Please add email\(s\)!/g`, try:

```
"<br>* Please add email(s)!<br>* Please add email(s)!<br>* Please add email(s)!<br>* Please add email(s)!".replace(/<br>\* Please add email\(s\)!/g,'')
```